# Android Development:Is it possible to roll back to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, adt

Currently and officially google will not release ADT for Eclipse anymore. I want to know are there any methods to use eclipse for android development now days?

Comment: Just because you can use the deprecated tools, doesn't mean you should IMO

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm trying to use android studio for 1year however it is full of problems stil..

Comment: I've been using Intellij for 2 years (plain Java and Android) and I haven't had any issues or used Eclipse since. No offense, but maybe whatever problems you're running into simply are unfamiliarity with it?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your notice, however comparing eclipse and android studio both have pros and cons but meanwhile developing codes with Android studio is so time consuming, e.g. when I'm going to debug app, it will take so many seconds to compile and make, but inside eclipse it was just a second to start debugging application. In addition I don't know which OS are you using. currently I'm using Android Studio in windows x64 with Corei5 and 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Ah, yeah. MacBook, i7, 16GB RAM. I use Genymotion also as my emulator. Could never get the Intel HAXM driver to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there appears to be nothing stopping you from using Eclipse. Lots of developers seem to be using Eclipse, based on questions asked here at Stack Overflow.

In the long term, Eclipse is building [Andmore](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore), which will be their recommended Eclipse-based solution. Presumably, Eclipse will support this option. Right now, [you can get the "p2" milestone](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore/downloads), with a 1.0 coming perhaps mid-2016. I have not tried Andmore and therefore cannot comment on how it is behaving.